# An error called " module 'numpy' has no attribute 'asscalar'" occurs when using AnomalyDetector

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
my_detector = AnomalyDetector(ts_dict)
```

This is my code and the error is:

```
    Input In [1], in scoreLuminolALLData(ts)
     36 ts_dict = ts.to_dict()
     37 score_v = []
    ---> 38 my_detector = AnomalyDetector(ts_dict)
     39 score = my_detector.get_all_scores()
     40 for timestamp, value in score.iteritems():
     41     #print(timestamp, value)

    File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/luminol/anomaly_detector.py:63, in AnomalyDetector.__init__(self, time_series, baseline_time_series, score_only, score_threshold, score_percent_threshold, algorithm_name, algorithm_params, refine_algorithm_name, refine_algorithm_params, algorithm_class)
     60 self.refine_algorithm_params = refine_algorithm_params or {}
     62 # Detect anomalies.
    ---> 63 self._detect(score_only)

    File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/luminol/anomaly_detector.py:104, in AnomalyDetector._detect(self, score_only)
    102     self.anom_scores = algorithm.run()
    103 if not score_only:
    --> 104     self._detect_anomalies()

    File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/luminol/anomaly_detector.py:111, in AnomalyDetector._detect_anomalies(self)
    107 """
    108 Detect anomalies using a threshold on anomaly scores.
    109 """
    110 anom_scores = self.anom_scores
    --> 111 max_anom_score = anom_scores.max()
    112 anomalies = []
    114 if max_anom_score:

    File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/luminol/modules/time_series.py:337, in TimeSeries.max(self, default)
    330 def max(self, default=None):
    331     """
    332     Calculate the maximum value over the time series.
    333 
    334     :param default: Value to return as a default should the calculation not be possible.
    335     :return: Float representing the maximum value or `None`.
    336     """
    --> 337     return numpy.asscalar(numpy.max(self.values)) if self.values else default

    File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py:320, in __getattr__(attr)
    317     from .testing import Tester
    318     return Tester
    --> 320 raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
    321                      "{!r}".format(__name__, attr))

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'asscalar'
```

Comment: [numpy.asscalar](https://numpy.org/doc/1.21/reference/generated/numpy.asscalar.html) was deprecated over 3 years ago. You probably need to upgrade `AnomalyDetector` version.